# how to call from one twilio account phone number to another twilio account phone number?

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-click-to-call, twilio-programmable-chat

Currently I am having 2 free trail twilio account. 
So I have 2 phone numbers, I per each account.
these 2 phone numbers are verified by each other.

So How to make a call from 1 twilio account phone number to another twilio phone number?

Comment: Which programing language are you using? This tutorial here should be all you need https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/make-calls

Comment: C#, Got the reference from this link https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/client/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-server-for-twilio-client?code-sample=code-generate-twilio-client-capability-token&code-language=C%23&code-sdk-version=5.x   ,,, after folliwing the steps it gave me the Error: Token does not allow outgoing calls.

Comment: Are you using your live credentials or test credentials? You should be using the live ones. Also, which country are you trying to call? From which country?

Comment: It got solved when I used the purchased number of twilio account